# scroll bar not visible in jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, scrollbar, jquery-ui-tabs

First up, I know this question is probably asked several times, but everyone's layout is different!

I have a mapping application and with a left side tool bar. This tool bar has jquery tabs. I cant get a scroll bar on these tabs. even after overloading `.ui-tabs-panel`. I know just by adding a `height:somepx` here gives me scroll bars, but thats not what i want. I want the height to be always till all the way down. I have tried several things but nothing works :(

I suspect its because of my other layout properties which are there to keep the layout liquid (make map adjust to screen sizes and keep left side bar constant).

Here is the stripped down version in Jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/exeguw/edit#source

Can some one please help me get the vertical scroll bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the tab div to the height of the #map div (adjusted for tab headers) after the tabs are created, then overflow will kick in and make the contents scrollable:

javascript:

```
function ResizeTabs() { 
   $("div.scroll-tab").height($("#map").height() - 80);
}

$(function() {
   $(window).resize(ResizeTabs);
   $('#tabs').tabs({
     create: ResizeTabs
   });
});
```

Updated [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/exeguw/15/edit).

EDIT: now handles window resizing as well!

Comment: +1 for a great solution! but this only works one time! If the browser is resized the scroll bar goes under the footer and disappears.

Comment: Updated the code to handle window resizing - I have had to do this recently, so I already had a resizing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://jsbin.com/exeguw/9/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: that shows me scroll bars, but It will scroll the tabs out of view too. I want the tabs to be seen always and just the contents scrolled.